# Issue with boost::program_options and positional parameters

Tags: c++, boost

gcc 4.7.2 / boost 1.58.0

I am trying code that looks like this, taken almost exclusively from the example in the documentation:

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;

po::options_description desc("Allowed options");

desc.add_options()
    ("help","produce help message")
;

po::positional_options_description pos_desc;

pos_desc.add("input-file",-1);

po::variables_map vm;

// The following line throws an std::logic_error
//  what() - error_with_option_name::m_option_style can only be one of
//           [0, allow_dash_for_short, allow_slash_for_short, allow_long_disguise
//            or allow_long]
po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc,argv).options(desc)
                                            .positional(pos_desc)
                                            .run(),
          vm);

...
```

A `logic_error` exception gets thrown at the line indicated by the comment, when I execute the application as:

`myapp filename1`

It shows usage when run with no (positional) arguments. Why does it throw when positional command line arguments are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the "input-file" argument to `desc` and then to `pos_desc`, not just the later. Here's an example of what I usually do.

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;

string fin_name;

try {
  po::options_description all_opt("Options");
  all_opt.add_options()
  ("help,h", "produce help message")
  ("input,i", po::value<string>(&fin_name),
   "input files with histograms")
  ;

  po::positional_options_description pos;
  pos.add("input",-1);

  po::variables_map vm;
  po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
    .options(all_opt).positional(pos).run(), vm);
  if (argc == 1 || vm.count("help")) {
    cout << all_opt << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  po::notify(vm);
}
catch(exception& e) {
  cerr << "\033[31mError: " <<  e.what() <<"\033[0m"<< endl;
  return 1;
}
```